# Error while writing dataframe with column length more that default value (256) to SQL warehouse

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to write a data frame from Spark to SQL warehouse table. One of the column in this table has values whoes length is greater than the default value of string (256) . As per this link , 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html
"maxStrLength" specifies the maximum length that can be used for string while loading to SQL warehouse, but this option is not helping me to increase the length of varchar from default value . Can you please suggest ? The below is my dataframe write statement that I am executing , let me know if you need more detail.

```
df.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
.option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall).option( "forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True").option("tempDir",tempDir).option("maxStrLength ","4000").option("dbTable",sqlschemaName + "."  + sqlDwhTbl)
.option("tableOptions", "DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN")
.mode("overwrite")
.save()
```

**error message :**

```
Underlying SQLException(s): - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: String or binary data would be truncated. [ErrorCode = 107090] [SQLState = S0001]
```

Answer (score 0):

The column is defined as varchar and you could change that to varchar(max) or investigate if any padding or double-byte characters are present in the data, that might be driving the total character count to exceed a column width definition greater than 4000 in DWH.

A quick test to try: `("maxStrLength ","3500")` and see if the string is accepted?

Comment: I am getting the same issue and setting maxStrLenght or increasing DB column size is not resolving the issue.

Comment: If the data exceeds the column definition, please see the following configuration example for writing the data to a temporary location for the necessary transformation and then copying the data back to SQL DW: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html#usage-batch

Comment: It is possible that you have too much data to insert into the target column and that you will need to transform some part of it. If you provide specifics, that would be helpful.